# Serilog event rate limit with notification about limiting actually happened

Tags: serilog

I throttle events for all sinks registered in a Serilog logger: only 5 events per minute are allowed to be emitted by any sink.

I need a record (a Serilog event) in all the sinks that the throttling actually took place, otherwise I don't know if the exact max. allowed amount of events has been logged per minute or more events have been throttled.

I use my own throttle approach similar to the ["official" PoC](https://gist.github.com/nblumhardt/d3baa1ea511242951e78). I create an `ILogEventFilter`, and in its `IsEnabled` method I check the current rate of the events and want to write my "throttling happened" event to all the sinks directly (otherwise, e.g. if I write this event via the logger, I'm in endless recursion):

```cs
public class EventFilter : ILogEventFilter
{
    public bool IsEnabled(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        var enabled = ThrottledInvoker<string>.Invoke( // internally counts the calls, the method signature is simplified for the sake of this code sample
                            () => // method to call if throttling takes place
                            {
                                // send additional events/records into the sinks about throttling
                                
                                var throttlingInfoEvent = new LogEvent(
                                    logEvent.Timestamp,
                                    logEvent.Level,
                                    null,
                                    MessageTemplate.Empty,
                                    new[] {
                                        new LogEventProperty("CustomMessage", new ScalarValue("Too many events of this kind.")),
                                    });
                                
                                // TODO: how to write to registered sinks?
                                sink1.Emit(throttlingInfoEvent);
                                sink2.Emit(throttlingInfoEvent);
                                // ...
                                // sinkN.Emit(throttlingInfoEvent);
                            },
                            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), // time period
                            5); // max. allowed event count per time period
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

I have found no `Logger.Sinks` property or anything alike. I understand that I can use reflection ([issue on GitHub](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1284)) to get private `_sinks` fields of my logger's aggregated sinks, but that smells.

I could initialize my filter before passing it to `LoggerConfiguration.Filter.With()` method, and pass all the sinks as my filter's constructor arguments. But the logger and sinks are configured by another component of the application which I don't have access to.

Is there a right/official way to do what I want?